# JaxB Unmarshal Exception: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element. Where have i gone wrong?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have two bean directories, one for request beans and the other for response beans, each containing their own ObjectMapper class.

I was able to succecssfully marshall my XML Beans (for the request) to a XML String before sending it off using the following below.

```
    JAXBElement<RequestblockType> requestblock = objectFactory.createRequestblock(requestblockType);
    m.marshal(requestblock, writer);
    // output string to console
    byte[] bytes = writer.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

I got my response back from server as an xml string and now trying to unmarshall back into my objects.

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResponseblockType.class);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
    jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(reader); //this line throws Exception
    um.unmarshal(reader);
```

On the line specified i get following exception:

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"responseblock"). Expected elements are <{}responseblockType>

Below is my XML and the top level bean class which is off the most importance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<responseblock version="3.67">
  <requestreference>X5727835</requestreference>
   <response type="AUTH">
  <merchant>
     <merchantname>Merchant1</merchantname>
     <orderreference>8900001233</orderreference>
     <tid>12341234</tid>
     <merchantnumber>00000000</merchantnumber>
     <merchantcountryiso2a>GB</merchantcountryiso2a>
  </merchant>
  <transactionreference>3-9-1598316</transactionreference>
  <timestamp>2014-08-18 11:56:40</timestamp>
  <acquirerresponsecode>00</acquirerresponsecode>
  <operation>
     <accounttypedescription>ECOM</accounttypedescription>
  </operation>
  <settlement>
     <settleduedate>2014-08-18</settleduedate>
     <settlestatus>0</settlestatus>
  </settlement>
  <billing>
     <amount currencycode="USD">3698</amount>
     <payment type="VISA">
        <issuer>Test Issuer1</issuer>
        <pan>1234123412341234</pan>
        <issuercountry>US</issuercountry>
     </payment>
     <dcc enabled="0" />
  </billing>
  <authcode>TEST</authcode>
  <live>0</live>
  <error>
     <message>Ok</message>
     <code>0</code>
  </error>
  <security>
     <postcode>0</postcode>
     <securitycode>2</securitycode>
     <address>0</address>
  </security>
   </response>
</responseblock>
```

package com.test.adapter.payment.test1.client.model.beans.responses;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "responseblockType")
@XmlRootElement
public class ResponseblockType {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String requestreference;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected ResponseType response;
@XmlAttribute(name = "version")
protected String version;

public String getRequestreference() { return requestreference; }
public void setRequestreference(String value) { this.requestreference = value; }
public ResponseType getResponse() { return response; }
public void setResponse(ResponseType value) { this.response = value; }
public String getVersion() { return version; }
public void setVersion(String value) { this.version = value;  }
```

}

Can anybody let me know where im going wrong? 
I can supply more information if possible. I saw from other post that adding an @XMLRootElement to my top level bean response class could help but it hasnt. Beside i didnt have to do this for my request when marshalling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root element name of the serialized XML responseblock differs from the one defined within
the bean class.

```
<responseblock version="3.67">
```

but

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ResponseblockType
```

It should be the following to match your annotation:

```
 <responseblockType version="3.67">
    ...
    ...
 </responseblockType>
```

Or you can override the default root element name in the `@XmlRootElement` annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="responseblock")
public class ResponseblockType
```

---

Another issue is that within the xml the root element responseblock isn't closed correctly at the end. The same problem seems to apply for the element response which s opened at line 4 of your xml

```
 line 4: <response type="AUTH">
```

but not closed.

Comment: Fixed the closing tags on the xml. it was there but SO was omitting it for some reason. 

So you are saying me defining ResponseBlockType as an XMLrootElement is incorrect?

Comment: No, but the names must be equal. So you have to change the name of the root element within the xml to ResponseBlockType or change the name of the bean class.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan. Thx for the edit. Improved the answer.

Comment: Thanks a million. I couldn't change the xml response. So overriding the default root element to @XmlRootElement(name="responseblock") worked.